# Como resolver o erro do arquivo SettingsFile

Tags: vb.net

Eu estou criando um projeto e nele, eu uso um tema pra ficar bonito. Quando eu coloquei o tema, tudo certo, não deu nenhum erro nem nada, só hoje, que deu esse problema, e eu não consigo ver o Form. O erro é o seguinte:

`The Settings start tag on line 6 position 4 does not match the end tag of SettingsFile`

Caso precise do arquivo `Settings.Designer` eu edito a pergunta.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, Brayan. FIz uma edição em sua pergunta a fim de torná-la mais clara e dentro dos padrões da comunidade. Sugiro que leia o [ask] e o [tour].  Outra coisa: - É sempre preferível que você coloque o fragmento de código relavante na pergunta, tal como o erro retornado. Imagens com códigos e erros não ajudam muito (principalmente se usar o celular) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos depurar esse arquivo, como diz o erro, na tag `Settings`, linha 6.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="My" GeneratedClassName="MySettings" UseMySettingsClassName="true">
     <Profiles>
        <Profile Name="(Default)" />
     </Profiles>
     <Settings> <!-- linha 6 é essa -->
        <Setting Name="HWID" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
            <Value Profile="(Default)" />
        </Setting>
     <Settings /> <!-- Erro aqui, tag não finalizada (wtf é isso?) -->
</SettingsFile> <!-- linha 11 é essa -->
```

O erro está na linha 10, onde você colocou `<Settings />` invés de `</Settings>`.
**Considere esse a versão corrigida:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="My" GeneratedClassName="MySettings" UseMySettingsClassName="true">
     <Profiles>
        <Profile Name="(Default)" />
     </Profiles>
     <Settings>
        <Setting Name="HWID" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
            <Value Profile="(Default)" />
        </Setting>
     </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Sempre quando for fechar uma tag, use `</` no início dela, não no fim dela.

Comment: funcionou! Mas agora está dando esse erro:

Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 5.

Comment: Remova todos espaços/caracteres de novas linhas do início do seu arquivo XML. Pode ser isso, clique ta seta para cima ao lado da postagem e no sinal de correto para considerar essa resposta como correta, irá me ajudar muito!

Comment: Obrigado, realmente funcionou, mas quando eu clico na seta, o número 1 apareçe e volta ao 0.. Quando você tinha me respondido pela 1° vez eu fiz isso e deu novamente o tal erro. Mas realmente, muito obrigado!